# Can we get email of event member on Facebook even via Facebook api

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Can we get email of event member  on Facebook even via Facebook api,

Is there any way to do it,i tried using graph tool but did not get email address.

Comment: I don't believe you can access emails other than the authenticated user.

Comment: i want to access email of my events mambers

Comment: Right, I don't believe that is possible via the API

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Elaborating on what @JaysonLane said, this won't be possible as a user needs to explicitly grant you access to read their email address and you would need a valid access_token for each individual user to get access to it

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/event/

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/login/email-permissions/

Comment: than you very much for your response.